# My gravatar is broken on most Stack Exchange sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-picture, gravatar

I just noticed the wrong Gravatar URL is used for my profile for most Stack Exchange profiles. This wasn’t happening last time I checked.

The correct one is used on:

- https://stackexchange.com/users/1179311/remco-haszing
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/1154610
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1154610

(Good) Gravatar URL: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fe52b3d3928f49a5057987549d39d1cb?d=identicon&r=PG

[image]

The wrong one is used on:

- https://askubuntu.com/users/83783/remco-haszing
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/146166/remco-haszing
- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/84412/remco-haszing
- https://superuser.com/users/176370/remco-haszing

(Bad) Gravatar URL: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/562f2a55fa628459f1f415eb25aa48ba?d=identicon&r=PG

[image]

I haven’t changed anything, especially not my email address. I also don’t see the issue for on any other user’s profiles. What could be causing this?

Comment: The "wrong" one is a default gravatar.   This usually happens when you change the gravatar picture.  The old one stays cached for a few days.

Comment: It’s not a caching issue. The URL is wrong, because the MD5 hash is wrong. It appears somehow my email isn’t properly available in the gravatar URL generation, even though it’s clearly set in the profile settings on all profile settings pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are events recorded for those profiles on June 9, 2020 that the profile picture was switched to an Identicon, likely caused by [this since-fixed bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344157/save-and-copy-to-all-communities-resets-profile-picture-if-its-set-to-gravata).

The solution here is to go to one of those profiles and manually switch them back to using Gravatar instead of Identicon and save the change across the network, but [that currently doesn't work either](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345627/profile-avatar-lost-on-several-sites-after-profile-edit-gravatar-replaced-with). So, until that is also fixed, you are currently stuck changing them back one by one. Alternatively, you could upload a profile picture manually and copy it to all sites, as that is said to be working properly.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this means I can't change all profile pictures in one action, but it explains the issue and I have verified that these profiles use identicon indeed. I can fix them one by one and did so for some profiles already. 